# Exception levels and logging

Tags: php, exception, logging, monolog

I have to develop a system of integration with different information systems.

In the development process, there will be cases when it is required in unpredicted situations to send notifications by mail, in other cases to record information in the log, or to send SMS in critical situations.

For logging and other notifications, I chose `Monolog`.

The question is, how do I organize work with `Exceptions` so that there are different levels of exceptions, and appropriate actions are performed (logging, etc.)?

I searched for information in different sources, found several descriptions. Some developers create 3 levels interfaces for Exceptions:

1. `UnloggedInterface` - all unprocessed errors are logged by default. This interface marks `Exceptions` that do not need to be logged at all.
2. `PreloggedInterface` — this interface marks exceptions that need to be logged anyway: it doesn't matter whether they are processed or not.
3. `OutableInterface` - this interface marks exceptions, the text of which can be given to the user.

I do not understand what should be the inheritance hierarchy of `Exception`  classes?

At what stage do you need to log `Exceptions`?
At the time of throwing exceptions?
or at the time of `Exception` handling?
and what to do with `Exceptions` that are not processed (how to log them?)?

May need to use `Monolog\ErrorHandler` ? (but I dont know how) ..

Please tell me how to be? Where can I see examples? Or where to read about it?

I would love to understand how this works. And look at examples of correct work with inclusions.

Also arrange examples from `GitHub`.

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: I apologize for my translation and many questions

Comment: nobody can help